# 8086 program for calculating multiplication of two matrices doesn't work

Tags: x86, matrix-multiplication, x86-16

i think my code has to be run correctly (it seems logical), but in the last loop the decrement instruction doesn't work and the program enters into a infinite loop.
here is my code:

```
; multi-segment executable file template.

data segment
matrix1 db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
matrix2 db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
n dw 3
row db 3
column dw 3
n2 db 9
result db 100 dup(0)
counter dw 3


ends

stack segment
dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax


mov bx,offset matrix1
mov bp,offset result


sub bx,n
dec bx    
push bx


new_row:

mov di,offset matrix2 
dec di 
pop bx   
add bx,n
inc bx
dec bp    
mov cx,n
mov counter,cx    ;counter checks if th columns are over for a raw


each_row:
inc bp
push bx

inc di
dec counter 
je -1,new_row

col:    
mov ah,[bx]
mov al,[di]
mul ah

add [bp],al       
inc bx
add di,n    
dec column  ;this is where the dec instruction stops working       
jnz col    
mov cx,n
mov column,cx   
pop bx    
dec row
jnz each_row


mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

Comment: What do you mean that `dec` "doesn't work"? How do you know that that instruction is the one that isn't working? Did you step through your code in a debugger? What is the value of `column` after three iterations of the loop? More than likely, the problem is actually the later `mov` instruction that modifies `column`

Comment: If you program in assembly, using a well known assembler, it is not a good idea to think that the CPU doesn't do things correctly. That is very unlikely. If the CPU wouldn't handle DEC properly, many, if not most programs would not work correctly, and people would have found out by now. If there is an error, assume it is yours, and not the CPU's.

Comment: i'm using 8086 assembler and there's an option where you can see the value of variables and that's how i see the amount of column remains the same and the dec instruction doesn't work. i just moved the value to the registers and now it's working properly. does anyone know why it happened?

Comment: You see in your debugger, *immediately after* the `dec` instruction, that the value of `column` did not change? As Rudy says, I find this hard to believe. I'm not surprised your code doesn't work as shown, but I doubt very much it is the `dec` instruction that is the problem. But I can't verify it; I don't have an 8086 (or virtualized 8086) to test the code on.

Comment: yes, immediately after the dec instruction, the value of column didn't change.

Comment: Can you show us a short screencast video of you stepping through the code in the debugger and showing the values not changing? I believe there is some issue in the communication here so that you and the other people here don't talk about the same thing in one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

You've put the buffer named *result* in the data section of your program.
At some point you want to refer to this buffer using the `BP` register. (You wrote `mov bp,offset result`. Herein lies the danger! **All memory addressing using `[bp]` uses the `SS` segment register by default.**

Solve the problem with your program by inserting a segment override prefix in the `add [bp], al` instruction:

```
col:    
mov ah,[bx]
mov al,[di]
mul ah
add ds:[bp],al    <<<<< See the   ds:  ?
```

Please note that *how to write a segment override prefix* is assembler specific.
These are other possibilities:

```
add [ds:bp],al
```

and :

```
ds:
add [bp], al
```

---

> ```
> dec counter
> je -1,new_row
> ```

What's this peculiar syntax supposed to do?